# Get outerWindowID from inner-window-destroyed

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Part of the Firefox extension I'm building gets the ID of 'inner windows' being destroyed, like this -

```
observer.add('inner-window-destroyed', function (subject, data) {
    var innerWindowID = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISupportsPRUint64).data;
    console.log('destroyed: '+innerWindowID);
})
```

This works OK, but I'd like to know if that observer can also get the ID of that inner window's outer window.

I can get an outerWindowID from another channel observer in my code, but I'm not sure how to get it from the above observer when an inner window is being destroyed.

Hope that makes sense...

I've referred to the details on these pages, but can't figure it out -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Windows

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Windows#Uniquely_identifying_DOM_windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observer only receives the window ID, accessing the window itself is no longer possible at this point. However, this message is always preceded by a `dom-window-destroyed` notification that gets the live window instance (as does the `outer-window-destroyed` notification). So you *could* register your observer for `dom-window-destroyed` notification as well and do something along these lines:

```js
var innerWindows = {};

...

observer.add("dom-window-destroyed", function(subject, data)
{
  var util = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);
  try
  {
    var innerWindow = util.currentInnerWindowID;
    var outerWindow = util.outerWindowID;
    innerWindows[innerWindow] = outerWindow;
  } catch (e) {}  // Ignore NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
});
observer.add("inner-window-destroyed", function(subject, data)
{
  var innerWindow = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISupportsPRUint64).data;
  if (innerWindow in innerWindows)
  {
    var outerWindow = innerWindows[innerWindow];
    delete innerWindows[innerWindow];
    console.log("destroyed: " + innerWindow + " (" + outerWindow + ")");
  }
});
```

I didn't try it but this looks like it would work.

Comment: Thanks @Wladimir, that makes sense, but I don't know how I would wrap that code and refer to it with an observer. 

I've only used the addon SDK to observe single events like this -

`observer = require('api-utils/observer-service');
observer.add('http-on-examine-response', function (subject, data) {
// examine the response subject`

Would I put your example into a function?

Comment: @Nils: I guess that you would have two observers with that API - I've adjusted my example accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again @Wladimir, [your example does appear to work](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1064726/latest/). You can test it by opening and closing a few tabs while viewing the console. It's made me realise though, that I probably don't need to refer to an ID combination to matching an inner window. It looks like the same incrementor is used for outer or inner windows, but it will always be unique reference to whatever it was set for.

Comment: @Nils: Yes, window IDs are globally unique. I thought that you were matching inner windows to a particular tab...

Comment: thanks guys excellent question and excellent answer, helped me out a lot, just posting a reference for other people for the mdn article about the basics of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Windows#Uniquely_identifying_DOM_windows