# How to identify tab close event for browser element [XUL/firefox]

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

I work on an addon that observes all the http requests and populate some info corresponding to each tab. I want to clear the data for the tab which I close. However, I can't get to identiy tab close event in a cleaner/saner way.
So I have the `contentWindow` (LoadContext -> associatedWindow) for which the request was made, and the `browser` for that content window (which is for the tab).

1. I realized that to do a `browser.addEventListener`, I will have to listen for `DOMNodeRemoved` event - which is [deprecated as per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) (and should rather use mutation observers). Moreover, I won't get the events when a popup window is closed.
2. If I do a `contentWindow.addEventListener` and look for `unload` event, the results are quite unpredictable. Some times, I don't get the events at all.
3. If I get this `tab` element from `gBrowser.tabs` and listen for `TabClose` event, I can get all close events for the tab. But then again, it won't inform of any popup-window closes (although I do get a `tab` element for the popup-window)

So what is the easiest/cleanest way to know any tab/popup-window close ? I don't use the addon SDK, btw.

EDIT : Looking for a simpler, valid-for-all-cases solution. ie. I get notified of close event be it a tab or a popup-window (or any other types of windows if they exist!). I believe that might be possible given that I hold a browser element which contains the DOM window, and the DOM get removed (unloaded) upon a close.

EDIT-2 : Realized that all the problem was due to one thing : there is no `TabClose` event from Firefox when the last tab closes (which is a window close). Life would have been much easier if we were notified of the tabs that get closed when a window closes. Any ways, I will go with a modified version of @Noitidart's solution - to have a separate window listener, in addition to the `TabClose` listener. And find the `tab` elements in it and do my clean up. Sigh! 
Will do a bit more search in this, and see if this qualifies for a bug/enhancement.
Thanks to @Noitidart and @Blargh for their suggestions.

Comment: Along the same lines of Edit2. FYI: There is no `TabOpen` event fired when a new browser window with tabs opens. Question though, what happens when a window closes with multiple tabs, I would think no `TabClose` event for any of those tabs huh?

Comment: Exactly. No `TabClose` when a window closes. What I do is to look for all tabs in it and do my cleanup. In fact, I have an expando property for the `browser` element per tab, and I use that to index my cached array. I can update my answer if you really want that.

Comment: Yes please, can you post it as a solution rather than editing in the topic question. Thx for the intelligent convo, I learned a lot here.

Comment: @Noitidart I just posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my modified version of @Noitidart's answer. I use an expando property on `browser` (eg: `_myextensionTabId` ) to index my cached array.

```
var WindowListener = {
/* Same as @Noitidart's listener */
  onOpenWindow : function(xulWindow) {
    /* Get DOM window, call other window specific modules init */
    myExtension.initWindow(domWindow);
    myHttpObserver.initWindow(domWindow);
  },
  onCloseWindow: function(xulWindow) {
    /* Get DOM window, call other window specific modules uninit */
    myExtension.uninitWindow(domWindow);
    myHttpObserver.uninitWindow(domWindow);
  },
};

var myHttpObserver = {
    ..  
    initWindow: function(window) {
      window.gBrowser.tabContainer
              .addEventListener('TabClose', tabClosed, false);
    }, 

    uninitWindow: function(window) {
      dump ("Uninit window http observer\n");
      window.gBrowser.tabContainer
                .removeEventListener('TabClose', tabClosed);
      for (var browser of window.gBrowser.browsers) {
        if (browser._myextensionTabId) {
          // Do any cleanup.
        }
      }
    },
  .. 
    /* Other http observer stuff, methods that sets the expando property etc. */
};

function tabClosed(e) {
  var browser = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser")
                           .gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(e.target);
  dump("Tab closed. \n");
  if (browser._myextensionTabId) {
    dump("My extension tab id : " + browser._myextensionTabId);
    // Do any cleanup
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I say hold a reference to the tab. This is how i do it in addons MouseControl and WorkspaceHopper.

so like check:

```
if (tab.parentNode) {

}
```

do a try catch too, if it catches then tab obviously doesnt exist.

but for tabClose you might as well use the tabclose event and for window popup, use the windowsMediator listner and listen to onWindowClose

```
var windowListener = {
    //DO NOT EDIT HERE
    onOpenWindow: function (aXULWindow) {
        // Wait for the window to finish loading
        let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        aDOMWindow.addEventListener('load', function () {
            aDOMWindow.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, false);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow);
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function (aXULWindow) {},
    onWindowTitleChange: function (aXULWindow, aNewTitle) {},
    register: function () {

        // Load into any existing windows
        let DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator(null);
        while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow);
        }
        // Listen to new windows
        Services.wm.addListener(windowListener);
    },
    unregister: function () {
        // Unload from any existing windows
        let DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator(null);
        while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
            windowListener.unloadFromWindow(aDOMWindow);
        }

        //Stop listening so future added windows dont get this attached
        Services.wm.removeListener(windowListener);
    },
    //END - DO NOT EDIT HERE
    loadIntoWindow: function (aDOMWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }

        //do stuff here

    },
    unloadFromWindow: function (aDOMWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        //do stuff here
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed I did. But that wouldn't help with a popup-window close! Is there an all-in-one solution ?

Comment: this is how i do it in WorkspaceHopper: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/237376/file/resources/workspacehopper/lib/main.js#L687

Comment: btw in the tabclose function, if you do `function (e) { var tab = e.target }` so then on close you can find your tab in the array of references and remove it.

Comment: also if keeping reference, `if (window)` does not always return false if window closed, you have to go `if (!window && window.closed)` i think window doesn go to garbage collect right away

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a simpler, valid-for-all-cases solution. ie. I get notified of close event be it a tab or a popup-window (or any other types of windows if they exist!). I believe that might be possible given that I hold a `browser` element which contains the DOM window, and the DOM get removed (unloaded) upon a close. 
Otherwise your answer might be the way to go. If I don't find an easy solution, will get back to accept your answer ;)

Comment: i saw you accepted the solution, i edited to update to the full code i use for windows listener

Answer (score 1):

For a one solution fits tab and window you can try window observers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#Windows

Probably want to use the `outer-window-destroyed` observer, I think each browser element within tab is an outer window. I'm not sure. It might trigger everytime the document changes though, so you would have to QI and get the tab and check if its closed/closing or still open.

Try it out, share with us what you learn, I'm very interested. On close i think it gets destroyed.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Tried it just now. Unfortunately, I get an `outer-window-destroyed` some 4 times, whenever a window closes. And I get one when a new tab opens! Besides, accessing the `window` is not possible directly other than getting a unique 64-bit id for that window [ as per answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345543/get-outerwindowid-from-inner-window-destroyed ]

Comment: Adding an observer sounded like that right thing to do, especially with the MDN description _"Extensions that cache information about windows may wish to observe this so they can release information when the window is destroyed"_ . I also played around with the other observers `dom-window-destroyed` and `xul-window-destroyed` but there are too many notifs, even when we don't expect to get one. And we don't get the `window` at the end.

Comment: Out of curiosity the window that closed, and you got 4 msgs with `outer-window-destroyed` did that window have three open tabs in it?

Comment: @Noitidart : nope. I only had one last tab open. It might be possible to identify which window was closed etc. But that is not so straightforward as Wladimir Palant puts in the answer (see the above link). So I didn't pursue that further. And then having separate tab and window listeners is the way to go. This whole problem was due to one thing - no `TabClose` event when the final tab closes. I had updated my question with that. See EDIT-2.